# Possible to Optimize Based on DB Structure Only - No Data

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There are some queries in my MySQL DB that seems to take a bit of time to execute. As the data is somewhat sensitive, it is not possible for me to share it with outsiders. However, I do need assistance trying to pinpoint what's slowing down the queries.

Can this be done by me only sharing the DB structure? And perhaps the queries that I find to be slow? Or do I also need to present the data?

Comment: You can always hash your sensitive data.

Answer (score 6):

Questions about improving performance should include:

- The full text of the query.
- SQL `CREATE` statements for the tables and indexes involved
  Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE\G`
- The version of the product you are using.
- Number of rows in each table.
- Query plan/explain output.
- Brief server hardware details including:

  - The amount of RAM
  - CPU info
  - Disk configuration; and
  - Network details (if applicable).
- Other important system/database configuration details
  Including `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`
- Expected results, and ideally, some sample data (it's OK to obfuscate).
  Sample data should be in the form:
  `INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES(A, B, C,...);`
  ...so it can be easily copied and pasted.
- Where possible, a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)*, or other off-site hosted runnable code.
- Any constraints on answers (e.g. no new indexes).
- Current and desired performance.

**The first two are vital**; the more of the rest that you can provide, the more likely your question is to attract high-quality answers.

<sub>** When it's working*</sub>

---

**MySQL experts: Please edit this *[Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/194636)* answer to improve it.**